# Div below other div in bootstrap

Tags: html, asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know this is kind of silly question but i m stuck with this for nearly 4 hours.I am new to bootstrap i m building a website for mobile view(and can also be viewed from desktop) using asp.net.I want a menu with collapse functionality in mobile i m using a div with class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" now i want another div that should come after this div.Here is my code

```
   <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top"><!--First div-->
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="GridView.aspx">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
<div id="Second"> <h2 style="text-align:center;">I want this div to come after the above div</h2></div>
```

This gives proper output when i view in mobile but when i run in desktop i am not able to see the Second div.

Thanks

Comment: I am using  Bootstrap Responsive v2.3.2 css.I am unable to post the whole css its too many characters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

specify a bootstrap class `row` or `row-fluid`

```
<div id="Second" class="row">
</div>
```

[**Plunker DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/D94ph9PhDrxfyNndjosi?p=preview)

Read <kbd>[Bootstrap Scaffolding](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html)</kbd>

Comment: No still same thing happens

Comment: @Hitesh, check out the demo i added

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Additional-CSS. Because navbar is `position: absolute`.

```
#Second {
    margin-top: 80px;
}
```

Comment: I tried margin-top property but now in mobile view there is too much white space between two divs